# How to verify if array exist and its length in fewest steps?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some if statement, where I want to verify the length of an array. Let's say it is the following:

```
if (object.someArray.length > 1){
  doSomething()
}
```

However, when someArray is not defined (maybe it is not defined for some object, which is possible), I get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Which makes sense, as `object.someArray` is not defined.

My question is: what is the best way to verify that the array exists AND its length, in fewest steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very generic and full test : if array exist and is not empty

```
if(object && object.someArray && object.someArray.length)
```

For your case :

```
if(object.someArray && object.someArray.length > 1)
```

Edit : For those who don't know this is called duck-typing : we aren't checking really if the object is an array, we're considering that if that object has a property **length**, it is an array. Lot of library do that. As long as you don't store different types of javascript object (string/array/object) in the same variable, this code is safe.

Comment: approach does fail for e.g. `var object = { someArray: {length:2} };` even though the above condition resolves to `true`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger this is called duck typing and this is what most of the libraries do :)

Comment: I'm aware of duck typing. But even though you might most probably be right with your approach, the OP should be aware of this case, of when to assure a certain type explicitly and when handling it more generous. For the given example an array sometimes only might be assigned/defined and sometimes it is not. I, in this case, would not bet for an object featuring a `length` property being an `Array` and therefore will favor type detection over duck typing (the latter one, by the way, being my preferred generic approach too).

Answer (score 2):

Try to check array through [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
if (Array.isArray(object.someArray) && object.someArray.length > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one single condition like

```
if (object.someArray && object.someArray.length > 1){
    //Do Something
}
```

if `object.someArray` is undefined, it will return false and the next condition will not be evaluated

Comment: approach does fail for e.g. `var object = { someArray: new String(12) };` even though the above condition resolves to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> the best way to verify that the array exists AND its length

The best way is to do exactly as you wrote:

```
if (array && array.length > 0 { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it this way.

```
if(object.someArray && object.someArray.length > 1) {
  doSomething();
}
```

If the someArray does not exist then it will be false and it will never check for its length because of the short-circuit.